# localeCompare shows inconsistent behavior when sorting words with leading umlaut characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Tested in latest Firefox and Chrome (which have a 'de' locale on my system):

```
"Ä".localeCompare("A")
```

gives me 1, meaning that it believes `"Ä"` should appear *after* `"A"` in a sorted order, which is correct.

But:

```
"Ägypten".localeCompare("Algerien")
```

gives me -1, meaning that it believes `"Ägypten"` should appear *before* `"Algerien"` in a sorted order.

Why? Why does it look past the first character of each string, if it says that the first character of the first string should appear after the first character of the second string when you check it on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have method just for your needs, copy paste this method:

Recursive parse of strings and give char locale compare result not string :)

**FINAL RESULT**
**Bug Fixed, added compare (incorrect stoppage or recursive loop) to entire strings:**

```
String.prototype.MylocaleCompare = function (right, idx){
    idx = (idx == undefined) ? 0 : idx++;

    var run = right.length <= this.length ? (idx < right.length - 1 ? true : false) : (idx < this.length - 1 ? true : false);


    if (!run) 
    {
        if (this[0].localeCompare(right[0]) == 0)
            {
                return this.localeCompare(right);
            }
            else
            {
                return this[0].localeCompare(right[0])
            }
    }

    if(this.localeCompare(right) != this[0].localeCompare(right[0]))
    {
        var myLeft = this.slice(1, this.length);
        var myRight = right.slice(1, right.length);
        if (myLeft.localeCompare(myRight) != myLeft[0].localeCompare(myRight[0]))
        {
            return myLeft.MylocaleCompare(myRight, idx);
        }
        else
        {
            if (this[0].localeCompare(right[0]) == 0)
            {
                return myLeft.MylocaleCompare(myRight, idx);
            }
            else
            {
                return this[0].localeCompare(right[0])
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return this.localeCompare(right);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your algorithm seems to work, did you program it yourself or do you have it from somewhere?

Comment: @wnstnsmth i did program it myself, but isn't fully functional (my bad here), hope I'll find time to fix it today, or tomorrow I will come back with the fix :)

Comment: Yeah, I found a bug: If string a is a subset of string b, like so (a === "Indien", b === "Indien (CA)"), then Firefox throws an error that myLeft[0] is undefined.

Comment: that's a big problem, please give me the string examples a='...' and b='...'  to debug a.MylocaleCompare(b); Never mind I'm tiered

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)#Printing_conventions_in_German

> “When alphabetically sorting German words, the umlaut is usually not distinguished from the underlying vowel, although if two words differ only by an umlaut, the umlauted one comes second […]
>   “There is a second system in limited use, mostly for sorting names (colloquially called "telephone directory sorting"), which treats `ü` like `ue`, and so on.”

Assuming the second kind of sorting algorithm is applied, then the results you are seeing make sense.

`Ä` would become `Ae`, and that is “longer” then your other value `A`, so sorting `A` before `Ae` and therefor `A` before `Ä` would be correct (and as you said yourself, you consider this to be correct; and even by the first algorithm that just treats `Ä` as `A` it would be correct, too).

Now `Ägypten` becomes `Aegypten` for sorting purposes, and therefor it has to appear before `Algerien` in the same sorting logic – the first letters of both terms are equal, so it is up to the second ones to determine sort order, and `e` has a lexicographically lower sort value than `l`. Therefor, `Aegypten` before `Algerien`, meaning `Ägypten` before `Algerien`.

---

German Wikipedia elaborates even more about this (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetische_Sortierung#Einsortierungsregeln_f.C3.BCr_weitere_Buchstaben), and notes that there are two variants of the relevant DIN 5007.

DIN 5007 variant 1 says, `ä` is to be treated as `a`, `ö` as `o` and `ü` as `u`, and that this kind of sorting was to be used for dictionaries and the like.

DIN 5007 variant 1 says the other thing, `ä` to be treated as `ae`, etc., and this is to be used mainly for name listings such as telephone books.

Wikipedia goes on to say that this takes into account that there might be more than one form of spelling for personal names (someone’s last name might be *Moeller* or *Möller*, both versions exist), whereas for words in a dictionary there is usually only *one* spelling that is considered correct.

---

Now, I guess the price question remaining is: Can I get browsers to apply the other form of sorting for German locale? To be frank, I don’t know.

It might surely be desirable to be able to chose between those two forms of sorting, because as the Wikipedia says personal names *Moeller* and *Möller* exist, but there is only *Ägypten* and not *Aegypten* when it comes to a dictionary.

Comment: Makes sense, BUT, there's this thing. When i do `["Ä", "A"].sort();` and `['Ägypten', 'Algerien'].sort();` i get equal results - umlaut comes second, so it seems that there is some sort of error inside of `compareLocale` after all. 
`

Comment: @Eternal1: `Array.sort` is not locale-aware, so that “normal” string comparison rules will be applied. And since strings do not have a simple `compare` method, I would assume that happens based on byte values, not characters.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer. I wonder if the implementation of localeCompare is documented somehwere. I thought it would do character-by-character unicode comparison, and not convert "ä" to "ae" first as in DIN5007 variant 2. Which doesn't make that much sense in my eyes.

Comment: I just saw that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#locales_argument mentions that there is `de-DE-u-co-phonebk` to request the German phone book sorting (don’t know whether that is explicitly implemented by common browsers). If that specifically exists for that purpose, then one might assume that the “other” sorting should be the default.

Comment: As to why the phone book sorting “makes sense”, take the _Moeller_ vs _Möller_ example from Wikipedia (or countless other ones) – both those surnames are pronounced the same in German, so if you were to look up someone based on you knowing “what their name sounds like” but not the exact particular spelling, it does make sense.